# Keras LSTM use softmax on every unit

Tags: python, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am creating a model somewhat similar to the one mentioned below:
[model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DOzw.png)

I am using Keras to create such model but have struck a dead end as I have not been able find a way to add SoftMax to outputs of the LSTM units. So far all the tutorials and helping material provides with information about outputting a single class even like in the case of image captioning as provided in [this link](https://machinelearningmastery.com/develop-a-deep-learning-caption-generation-model-in-python/).

So is it possible to apply SoftMax to every unit of LSTM (where return sequence is true) or do I have to move to pytorch.

Comment: it would be helpful if you could provide some of the code you have tried using

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is: yes, it is possible to apply to each unit of LSTM and no, you do not have to move to PyTorch.

While in Keras 1.X you needed to explicitly state that you add a TimeDistributed layer, in Keras 2.X you can just write:

```
model.add(LSTM(50,activation='relu',return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dense(number_of_classes,activation='softmax'))
```

Comment: Shouldn't return_sequences be True?